# Remove imgs from container if container possess a div with a certain class

Tags: jquery, find, logic

I have divs with imgs in them. However, a few of these divs also have a span as the first element within the div. This span represents the 'label' for the imgs within this div.

I have a script going where if i hold alt and click on this 'packet' div, it'll be removed. However, i do not want to remove the packets that have the labels in them. For those ones, just removing the imgs within is good enough.

I've been having trouble establishing that logic. As well, to convey the ability to delete by clicking and holding the alt key, i attempted to have a css property change some colors as a cue. This too, does not work.

```
$(".Card_Packet").click(function (e) {
    if (e.altKey) {

        $(this).live('hover', function(event) {
            if (event.type === 'mouseover') {
                $(this).css({
                    'border-color': 'red'
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).css({
                    'border-color':'black'
                });
            }
        });

        if ($(this).find('Sect_Header')) { //if the div contains the label, remove only the images. Otherwise, remove the whole thing.
            $(this).remove('img');
        } else {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

I'm sure it has something to do with my order of operations.

Comment: Should be `.find('.Sect_Header')` the dot is missing

Comment: what is 'Sect_Header'?  it looks like you are searching for an element with a tag name of 'Sect_Header'.

Comment: I did forget the dot, but it didn't fix it. Calum provided what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($(this).children(":first").is("span")){ //If the div contains the label, remove only the images..
   $(this).find('img').remove();
}else{ //Otherwise remove packet div
   $(this).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is some working code:

```
$(".Card_Packet").click(function (e) {

    if (e.altKey) {

        if ($('.Sect_Header', this).length > 0) { 
            //if the div contains the label, remove only the images. 
            //   Otherwise, remove the whole thing.

            $('img', this).remove(); //removes the images

        } else {

            $(this).remove(); //removes the whole thing

        }

    }

});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xwmwD/

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing will remove the whole div.  Just do this to remove only the images from any div:

```
$('select-your-div img').remove();
```